# Where can I get logo inspiration?

Tags: website-design, logo, conceptualization

I am wondering if there is any free online place that I can use to get some design ideas.
I want to get those ideas and then use a service like Fiverr to get a for example logo designed for me.

For example I want my logo shows the concept of `insight`, but I don't know what graphic shows that concept. Is there anywhere on the web or any book that has some design samples for different concepts?

Maybe a more appropriate question is: for a person who is not a gifted graphic designer, is there a way to find some design ideas? For example how to find a design idea for the concept of `insight`? Is there a book or a resource that can help?

Comment: So you want someone to give you an idea for free, then someone else to make it for you for $5? Hrrrm..... that's asking for quite a lot... see also [How would you like your graphic design](http://colinharman.com/portfolio/how-would-you-like-your-graphic-design/)

Comment: life is full of free ideas.

Comment: @user568458 I do not want anybody to work for free. However, there are a lot of free resources, such as open source codes, free images, etc. I was wondering if there is similar thing for design ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are millions of communities to get inspiration from do a Google search:

- [Behance](https://www.behance.net/search)
- [Dribbble](http://dribbble.com/search?q=logo)
- [DeviantArt](http://www.deviantart.com/designs/logos/)

Google *[logo inspiration](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=logo%20inspiration)*:

- [LogoPond](http://logopond.com/)
- [Creattica](http://creattica.com/logos/)
- [Logofaves](http://logofaves.com/)
- [Logogala](http://www.logogala.com/)
- [Logosauce](http://www.logosauce.com/)
- [LogoMouse](http://www.logomoose.com/)
- [LogoLounge](http://www.logolounge.com/)
- [LogoGallery](http://www.logogallery.net/)
- [LogoCrush](http://logocrush.com/)
- [Logorium](http://www.logorium.com/)
- [LogoGalleria](http://www.logogalleria.com/)
- [LogoLover](http://www.logolover.com/)
- [LogoTalkz](http://www.logotalkz.com/)