# Source of graphic design ideas

Tags: design-principles, designers

I love creating designs. Personally I would love to take my time, think up and create every little thing in my design. But on some cases I'm working with some company I have not so much idea of what they are all about. And I'll have to take days reading up about them and understanding them fully.

My question really is; is there like a reliable way/or website to get ideas through others works? Not copying or manipulating their works really, but getting inspired and geared into what the company expects. I mostly use google, but that's so random and vague.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include a concrete example of what you mean?

Comment: See similar question [Where can I get logo inspiration?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26375/where-can-i-get-logo-inspiration). The question deals with a subset of GD but the top 2 resources are useful. Also this question is pretty vague and there are plenty of results that can easily be found from a search engine.

Comment: There's two topics here: how to research a clients company and where to find designs from others. Both, alas, are really broad questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Dribbble
- Forrst/Tavern
- Behance
- Pinterest (which is usually curated with pins from above sites)
- Tumblr
- ...and trusty old Google
- I'd also mention to try out twitter and following your favorite designers for inspiration. *I follow a few illustrators solely for some of the works they do and sometimes seeing their work gives you some great ideas, even isn't the exact thing you were searching for.*

Comment: I love this list - I'm just going to add that sometimes you will find yourself inspired from random books, movies, commercials, posters, nature, objects around you.  Once you key your eyes into design, you start to see it everywhere around you.  Instagram is also pretty good, and so is twitter.  Sometimes you can still find some good stuff on deviantart too!  ALSO SKILLSHARE!  it can be invaluable.  Not just for getting quick inspiration, but for learning skills and how other artists work!